# Mutiple SSL For one domain

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Firstly forgive me for my lack of knowledge on this subject.

The Scenario is that i run a small hosting company and i wish to have ssl on all my servers. Issue is that i want to install a Extended validation SSL on my main domain and normal wild card SSL on the rest of the servers and sub domain. Is it possible to install 2 ssl for a single domain?.

example.

www.*****.com will have extended validation SSL and the sub-domain.

Secure.*****.com will use a wild card SSL

If anyone can give me some advice or point me towards some guides/documentation, it would be much appreciated.

I do not need a product/service recommendation as I have a provider in mind and understand that this is not the purpose of SE sites.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. Neither `www.*.com` nor `Secure.*.com` is a valid domain name for a wildcard certificate. `*.example.com` would be valid as would `*.any.example.com`.

Comment: I will **+ kasperd** on this , You can have wild card certificate for *.yourdomainname.com only. Though you can opt for multisite SSL certificate .

Comment: Sorry for asking such basic question, You mean to say wildcard ssl cant be applied for domain name say www.example.com , Can you let me know what would be the right solution. If i want a extended validation ssl for my root domain www.***.com and wild card ssl for the rest of the sub domain plus ssl for various server IP's.

Comment: Please use a name like `example.com` for the domain you own, not asterisks. We can't differentiate between your placeholder and wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a certificate for domains you own. This means, that you cannot get a certificate for www.*.com, because you don't own all the matching domains (like google.com). Apart from that browsers support wildcards only in the leftmost part of the host name.

What you can do is to either have a certificate for each domain you own, or a certificate containing all domains you own using subject alternative names, or something in between (multiple certificates, each for multiple domains). You also need to consider that older browser like IE6 support only a single certificate per IP address. Newer browsers can work with multiple certificates per IP address by using SNI (Server Name Indication).